# Dockerfile to run nodejs static-content in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, kubernetes

Need an advice to dockerize and run a node JS static-content app on K8s cluster.

I have a static web-content which I run "npm run build” into the terminal which generates /build and direct my IIS webserver to /build/Index.html.

Now, I started creating a Docker file, how do I point my nodeJS image to invoke /build/Index.html file

```
FROM node:carbon
WORKDIR /app
COPY /Core/* ./app
npm run build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", ".app/build/index.html" ]
```

Please how can I run this app only on node v8.9.3 and
npm 5.6.0 ?

Any inputs please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the version of node specifically:

```
FROM node:8.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:**

1. `package.json` is under `Code` directory.
2. `npm run build` will be running outside of the container and a `build` directory will be created in `Code` directory.
3. We will copy the whole `Code/build` directory under `/app` directory of the container.
4. We will copy `package.json` to `/app` folder and will run the website through scripts available in `package.json` file.

**Solution:**

I would say add a `script` named `start` in the `package.json` and call that script from Dockerfile's `CMD` command. The script would look like:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index.html",
  },
```

And the `Dockerfile` would look like:

```
FROM node:8.9.3

# Make app directory in the container.
RUN MKDIR /app

# Copy whole code to app directory.
COPY Code/build/ /app

# Copy package.json app directory.
COPY package.json /app

# make app directory as the working directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies.
RUN npm install -only=production

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8080

# Start the process
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: @Mishra- Thanks for it .  I created the same, it creates an image but when in Docker run, container wont start. Since "npm run build" generates all my binaries to /build folder and npm engine should pick up index.html (package.json points to index.html) so I added "npm run build" after install dependencies . I got few errors <pre> <code> [13:23:24] Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error: Error: File not found with singular glob: /build/content/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.css
[13:23:24] Plumber found unhandled error. How can I fix it ?